# Dynamic values in material ui's makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have some styles stored in a database so users can restyle their components -  along the lines of:

```
const stylesFromDatabase = {
backgroundColor: "blue",
color: "red"
}
```

Is it possible to bring these styles into material UI's makeStyles - perhaps something like this?- edited -

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    textField: stylesFromDatabase => ({
    width: "100%",
    ...stylesFromDatabase
  }),
```

Alternatively, is there anything I can use to smoosh together the classes generated by makeStyles and a javascript object?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**,
 It's absolutely possible to include a `JavaScript` object into `makeStyles`.
Thanks to the `spread` operator.

> Advice is to spread over the object first, so that you can easily override any styles.
>   Therefore it's preferred to do as follows.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  textField: {
    ...stylesFromDatabase,  // object
    width: "100%",
    color: "green", // this would override "red" (easier fine tuning)
  },
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I see where you're coming from, but that would bring the styles outside of the textField I'm trying to style. I've edited my original q to show what I'm trying now, but still can't get it to work. Btw I haven't forgotten to pass stylesFromDatabase in.

Comment: Ok, so from your edit. What you want to specifically pass that object to `textField` only, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass all values from the database (the first block on my post).

Comment: Kindly see my updated answer. You don't necessarily need a callback function. We can `spread` over the object directly within `textField`. That syntax should serve your purpose well.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

For the benefit of future posters, the code in my original post worked perfectly, I just had something overriding it later! (Without the callback function it was undefined)

Comment: Alright, glad to help. It would then be crucial to explain this part `Without the callback function it was undefined` for others.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future posters, the code in my original post worked perfectly, I just had something overriding it later! (Without the callback function it was undefined) – H Capello just

Comment: well, instead of adding a new answer, why don't you edit your question and add this quote into at the end of that question?